# How to deactivate functionality of a aui:checkbox label?

Tags: java, jsp, checkbox, alloy-ui

Iam creating checkboxes through a loop (see picture).

```
<%for(String s : mSeriesIDs_cfg) { %>  
<aui:input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup" label="<%=s%>" value="<%=GetterUtil.getString(portletPreferences.getValue(s, defaultSerieConfig))%>" />
<%} %>
```

[image]

The checkboxes itself are working correctly, but if I click on a label(name) of a checkbox, the first checkbox gets activated/deactivated (in the picture, if I click on the name 'Messreihe4', the first checkbox change to unchecked).
How can I stop the functionality of this?

Comment: That is the functionality of labels. You could declare your own tag, that would not use labels, but something else. Or remove label and add this text next to your checkbox.

Comment: I don't think that labels have functionality at normal. I can't remove the label tag, otherwise aui takes automatically the name as label, that would be worse. I never created an own tag, how complex is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow these:

(1) Create the checkbox with *no* label.

(2) Add text to right of checkbox (in textbox or otherwise)

(3) Now align them next to each other

(4) This should now remove that functionality.

---

(Note this is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/0vpgnsey/), but a similar design/implementation should also work for jsp)

so;

```
<input type="checkbox" /><a>Label 1</a>
      ^                      ^
      |                      |
  checkbox with no label     |
                             |
               single label placed next to checkbox
```

Comment: That works, but not for aui-elements. I would like to stay with this, because iam doing everything with it. An other, non aui solutin is: <div class="checkbox">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxThree" id="checkBoxThree">
        <label for="checkBoxThree">Receive in-app notification</label>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

@MrCoder: 'aui:input' needs the name tag, which is automaticly the label, if no label tag is defined.
I solved it with the help of your solution:

```
  <%for(String s : mSeriesIDs_cfg) { %>  
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <aui:input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup" label="" value="<%=GetterUtil.getString(portletPreferences.getValue(s, defaultSerieConfig))%>" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=s%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<%} %>
```

I just added the label tag without a content.
That isn't a clean solution, but it works best so far.

Answer (score 0):

For people still searching for the answer: if you add an `id` to the `<aui:input type="checkbox" ...></aui:input>` element, it will work. When you click the label, it will check/uncheck the correct checkbox.